# Text Zooming Effect Trembling

Tags: python, animation, cairo, moviepy, cffi

I created a text zooming animation with MoviePy and Gizeh. However the results turned out different when the code is run on different OS. The following two gifs are generated by the same python code. The effect looks pretty good on MacOS, but poor on Linux.

pretty good on MacOS

[image: pretty good on MacOS]

effect trembling on Linux

[image: effect trembling on Linux]

I'm sure that the libraries(MoviePy, Gizeh, Cairocffi, cffi, etc.) versions are the same on both systems. I also tried high fps or downsize the test but it didn't work.

I don't know if this may be an issue or bad coding from my side.

I tried to find out what caused this issue. I found the return values of 
 the function *ctx.text_extents(txt)* in gizeh.py Line 489 ( same as *cairo_text_extents*, in cairocffi library, context.py, Line 2003) varies every frame on Linux. And on Mac the function always return the same values. However, even if I fixed the values, the effect remained the same.

```
import sys
import gizeh as gz
from moviepy.editor import *

def make_frame(t):
    surface = gz.Surface(360, 180, bg_color=(0, 0, 0))
    text = gz.text('ENLARGE', fontsize=40, fontfamily='Arial Unicode',
                   fill=(255,255,255), xy=(180, 90), fontweight='normal')
    text = text.scale(1+0.5*t, center=[180, 90])
    text.draw(surface)
    return surface.get_npimage()

child_clip = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=3)
child_clip.write_gif('Result.gif',fps=24)
```

---

I have locate this problem in Cairo library. I wrote a simple demo to create a sequence of images enlarging the text string. And I printed the return values of the function cairo_text_extents() which indicated the extents of the string. I run the same code on Linux and MacOS. The values stayed the same on MacOS. While on Linux, the values varied every frame. Tring to figure out why.

```
#include "cairo.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int draw (const char* filename, float t)
{
    cairo_surface_t *ImageSurface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,360,360);

    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(ImageSurface);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1., 1., 1.);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_matrix_t matrix;
    float scale = (1+0.5*t);
    float offset = -(0.5*t)/2*355;
    matrix.xx = scale;
    matrix.xy = 0;
    matrix.x0 = offset;
    matrix.yx = 0;
    matrix.yy = scale;
    matrix.y0 = offset;

    cairo_set_matrix(cr,&matrix);

    cairo_font_options_t *font_options = cairo_font_options_create();
    cairo_font_options_set_antialias(font_options,CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);
    cairo_font_options_set_hint_style(font_options,CAIRO_HINT_STYLE_NONE);
    cairo_font_options_set_hint_metrics(font_options,CAIRO_HINT_METRICS_OFF);
    cairo_set_font_options(cr,font_options);

    cairo_select_font_face (cr, "Arial Unicode",
                CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
                CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr,60);

    cairo_text_extents_t *text_extents = new cairo_text_extents_t;
    cairo_text_extents(cr,"ENLARGE",text_extents);
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n",text_extents->width,
                                text_extents->height,
                                text_extents->x_advance,
                                text_extents->y_advance,
                                text_extents->x_bearing,
                                text_extents->y_bearing);
    int x_shift = -text_extents->width/2-text_extents->x_bearing;
    int y_shift = -text_extents->height/2-text_extents->y_bearing;
    int x = 180 + x_shift;
    int y = 180 + y_shift;
    cairo_move_to (cr, x, y);
    cairo_text_path(cr,"ENLARGE");
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr,0,0,0);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(ImageSurface,filename);

    cairo_font_options_destroy(font_options);
    delete text_extents;
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(ImageSurface);


    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        char filename[256] = "";
        sprintf(filename,"result_%d.png",i);
        float t = 1.0/10 * i;

        draw((const char*)filename,t);
    }
    printf("hello world!!!\n");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable font hinting in Cairo (or fontconfig). I guess this means to set `CAIRO_HINT_METRICS_OFF` and/or `CAIRO_HINT_STYLE_NONE`. However, I do not even know what Gizeh is and so I cannot tell you how to disable hinting there.

Comment: Gizeh is a Python library for vector graphics based on cairo.[link](https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh)
Now I have locate this problem in Cairo library. I found that if I set the cairo_matrix_t for cairo_t, function cairo_text_extents() would return different values of cairo_text_extents_t on Linux. But on MacOS, the return valuse of cairo_text_extents stayed the same.
I disabled the font hinting but it didn't work. Also tried to disable font antialias and hint metrics. 
I'm not sure this may be a problem caused by os or font file(ttf) or font options.